# Regex rule to exclude url with specific word

Tags: php, regex

When I search for " abc 920 def" on my site, the domain fires:

```
http://www.domain.com/?s=abc+920+def
```

Then, this redirection rule:

```
​/?(.*)=(.*)920(.*)
```

will redirect it to a category:   `domain.com/all-things-920/`

The problem now is that I have some other pages that generate random numbers for receipt pages, such as:

```
/store/receipt/?ouid=0955a8980823k920
```

Because that url contains `920`, it will redirect it to the category `domain.com/all-things-920/`  which I don't want.

I tried playing with some regex combinations without any luck.
Is there a way to exclude the regex rule if the url contains  `ouid` in it?

I tried:  `/?(?!ouid)(.*)=(.*)920(.*)`   without luck.

When I use the rule  `/?s=(.*)920(.*)`,  it will place `/?/`  in the middle of the url path. For example  `domain.com/?/all-things-920/`

Comment: Do you really want to match on all things not `ouid=`, or just match on anything `s=`

Comment: Just matching on  s= would work better. Any advice how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)s=.*?920[^&]*(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ /all-things-920/? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not want to go the .htaccess way, but it seems to be my only choice now, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want regex that matches on any `920` string against `/s=` then you might try:

`/s=(.*)920(.*)`

Comment: When I use the rule /?s=(.*)920(.*), it will place /?/ in the middle of the url path. For example domain.com/?/all-things-920/

Comment: @user2806378 not sure what you're asking?

Answer (score -1):

That redirection logic should belong in PHP, not in the .htaccess or whatever it is you are redirecting.

Then you can easily check the `$_GET['s']` value.

You can redirect with `header("Location: www.domain.com/wherever");`